Activemq unable to send JMS message due to NoClassDefFoundError
I am having problems with my activemq application. After starting it if I send a dummy JMS message to queue it throws below error:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

I have added javax.xml.bind dependency too, but no luck

You say you "added javax.xml.bind dependency," but you don't say how you added it? Can you elaborate on that? Also, what do you mean "without any application running"? If no application is running how are you able to send a message from your application? Do you mean that you had no consumers running?

Added In the pom.xml of the application that would consume the messages that im sending from activemq. Im not sending anything from my application,  im sending from activemq console.

After a lot of trial & error, i found that my env variable was set to jdk 11 which doesn't support javax/xml/bind , i switched it to jdk8 ( organization std ) and it worked.
